# AS3 Air 3.3 app on Android always crashes after 4 seconds

Tags: android, air, crash, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, flashdevelop

I'm testing on an HTC Sensation, running android 4.0.3.
I'm publishing using FlashDevelop 4.0.3 and using the Air Mobile AS3 App template.

All the application does is display a Rectangle using:
this.graphics.beginFill(0x00FF00);
this.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
Just so I can see that its actually publishing something.

The app runs correctly if I publish to the desktop, however when I switch to publishing it to the phone, the problem I'm facing is that the application publishes and runs on the phone, but only for a few seconds.. usually about 4 seconds and then it crashes out.

The really weird thing is that it was working fine about a week ago.. I'm not sure what's changed since then, but yeah it started happening this morning, I tried everything I could think of... including stripping everything out of the app and also doing a factory reset of my phone... nothing seems to have helped...

has anyone else had this problem? or have any ideas on what might be causing it or how to fix it? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

---

Update:
it seems changing the render mode to "auto" instead of "direct" stops the crashing, which is great, however if you need to use direct for stage3d content this doesn't really help. anyone else having this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the source code of your application? I do too have HTC Sensation but my firmware version is 2.3.6. It would be interesting to test it.

Comment: sure, you can download the source files here: http://peteshand.net/downloads/blank_air_app.zip

but it seems to be happening with all my applications which have previously worked fine, so my guess is that there is some incompatibility with HTC Sensation, android 4 and flashdevelop.

let me know if it works for you.

cheers
pete

Answer (score 0):

I just updated my XPERIA ARC to ICS and now I'm having problems with AIR apps as well. Seems the app is not getting the Click/Touch interactions. Some InteractiveObjects like TextInput gets the click and focus as it should, but Buttons are not working. And I'm using latest Flex/AIR sdks...
But I'm pretty sure we are in Adobe/Apache hands until they update the AIR with a fix.